# How to add a new language for highlight in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm writing a document in `rmarkdown` with the [thesisdown](https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown) template.

Related to the issue [thesisdown-41](https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown/issues/41): how can I add a new language for highlighting which is currently not supported?

The project mentioned in the link is derived from [bookdown](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood `bookdown` uses `pandoc` for tranforming markdown to HTML/PDF/.... From pandoc's manual at http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#syntax-highlighting we get:

- The library used for highlighting is [skylighting](https://github.com/jgm/skylighting).
- The list of available languages can be retrieved with `pandoc --list-highlight-languages`

Comment: Thank you very much! So I assume for adding a new language for highlighting first `skylighting` needs new release and `pandoc` need new releases as well with the updated version right?

Comment: @mavogel Yes, that is my expectation. Also note that you will most likely need development versions of various packages when using a very recenr pandoc version, c.f. https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/pandoc-2/

Answer (score 2):

Slightly off topic, but I just worked out how to do this in RMarkdown rather than Bookdown.  I suspect you'll need this and maybe a little more.

Passing extra arguments to Pandoc via the YAML front-matter:

```yaml
output:
  html_document: 
    highlight: haddock
    pandoc_args: ["--syntax-definition", "cobol.xml"]
```

Obtain the XML syntax definition file from somewhere (or create it).  I got my COBOL one from:

```sh
wget http://kde.6490.n7.nabble.com/attachment/1163657/0/cobol.xml.gz
```

The syntax of the highliting file is as used by the Kate project in KDE.

Obtain the pre-req `language.dtd` file, this is some deep dependency with pandoc.

```sh
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/highlighting-kate/master/xml/language.dtd
```

If've just added the two files to my git repo, plus the YAML lines to my RMarkdown, and everything then worked on other developers machines.